# problems with the scope variable over communication between the directives in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing scripting using angularjs.I have created an app and included some selfdefined directives into it.I am getting problem when one of my directives is communicating with the other one and I am not able to access the scope variables in one directive from the other.I am often confused with the usage of **this** and **$scope** in angularjs.Help me out on this

Here is my html file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Js/directiveScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="directiveController">
<userdirective secondary></userdirective>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the javascript file im working on

```
var directiveApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

directiveApp.controller("directiveController", function($scope) {

});

directiveApp.directive("userdirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        controller : function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "hi";
        },
        link : function() {

            alert("from userdefined element");
        }
    };

});

directiveApp.directive("secondary", function() {
    return {
        require : "userdirective",
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, userdirectivectrl) {
            alert(userdirectivectrl.message);
        }
    };
});
```

When Iam doing this,the directive named **secondary** is giving an alert with undefined instead of showing original value.If I change the declaration of variable in the controller of the first directive to **this.message**,it works fine.why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`alert(scope.message);`

instead of

`alert(userdirectivectrl.message);`

The message is defined on scope not controller.

Comment: Thanks @Chandermani..it helped me a lot.By the way, what is the difference on variable declaration using the keyword "this" in the controller and by using $scope in the controller again?

Comment: this has different meaning different context in javascript. For simplicity sake this in your case referred to the class (controller). But your message variable was defined not on the controller, but on the parameter that has been passed to the controller `$scope`